# How can I use `tc` with diffrent parameters on few virtual interfaces?

Tags: tc

I need to simulate network environment with bad network connections for about 1000 hosts.

Can `tc` (with netem) be used with virtual network interfaces (like eth0:0, eth0:1)?

When I try to use `tc` on many virtual interfaces with different parameters - it seems that all virtual interfaces have one `tc` configuration.

My problem is similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186010/netem-and-virtual-interfaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can `tc` be used with virtual network interfaces

Yes.

> (like eth0:0, eth0:1)?

No.

Those aren't virtual network interfaces. They're aliases for network interfaces. There's a huge difference.

It's an oldfashioned way to specify more than one address per interface, instead of the modern approach of `ip address add/change/replace/del $ip dev $interface`.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/alias.txt

> IP-aliases are an **obsolete** way to manage multiple IP-addresses/masks
>   per interface.

And that's pretty much all you can use them for. Best not to use them at all. Aliases make you think they're virtual devices with all the bells and whistles but they're not. Aliases exist in name only - they don't do anything.

If you need a genuine virtual network device, you can have a look at bridge devices (virtualization), or tun/tap devices (openvpn). For `tc` specifically, you might also be interested in [IMQ / IFB](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/ifb).

If you just want to filter by IP address, you can specify those in `tc filter` or mark them in `iptables` and then filter by mark.

Comment: When I'm adding new address I can't see it in `ifconfig`. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes... even the `ifconfig` manpage says "Please use `ip link` ..." ;-) ...basically you don't use `ifconfig` and `route` anymore. Now it's `ip link`, `ip address`, `ip route`, ...

Comment: Oh dear. I have to learn Linux again...